# What does the train guard shout in Philosopher's Stone and Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In some of the Harry Potter movies, the train guard at King's Cross station shouts something. It sounds like "Egg jewel on!"

*Philosopher's Stone*:

*Chamber of Secrets*:

Must be some kind of railway slang, or maybe in a thick accent.

Anyone know?

Comment: Sounds to me like 'vector alert'. Good question!

Comment: It might also be 'bags are all on', which is more plausible. It's conceivable that in old-school railways where there were luggage compartments that a guard might be responsible to for loading luggage onto a train. I'm not sure that's it, though.

Comment: How do you even mishear that...

Comment: @theonlygusti Well of course you're going to hear "egg jewel on" after being primed like that!

Comment: I have also had this question for a long time. But I hear "Vancouver". I even think it is "obviously" this word. My brain simply cannot interpret the sound any other way! (However, I do of course realise that a muggle train service between London and Vancouver seems rather implausible.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To me it sounds like he's yelling

> "Stand clear o' th' doors!",

The conductor is warning people not to get in between the doors as they close

---

[In a comment on the first video that was linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDcNEzPb0EM&lc=z12uzle4homsdvuvk22ijh14fqe3xpuqr04.1476444974188154), user Requi says that the German translation of the film has the Conductor saying

> "Get away from the platform."

I can't find a German translation of the script, and even in the original script there is no mention of a conductor saying anything in this scene.

Comment: The more I listen to it, the more I can hear "Stand clear o' th' door!"

Answer (score 15):

He's saying ...

> *"[Please] **Stand clear o'**[f] **th'**[e] **door**[s]"*

Which is a [standard announcement](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/246698/response/612672/attach/html/6/District%20DVA%20Script%20D%20Stock.pdf.html) on British rail services before departure to ensure that those boarding the train are out of harm's way before they move off.

---

On a related note, the doors on the Hogwarts Express are [manually operated](https://youtu.be/pEKA6rmVfW8?t=2m37s), so the guard is almost certainly shouting about a *standard service train* (one with powered doors operated by a conductor) on the next platform over.

Since the trains run on a schedule, it's not much of a coincidence that the same conductor is on platform 10 (or 9) a year later.

Comment: Yup. As a minor nitpick, the doors on the standard service train would certainly not be automated. They would be [power operated](https://www.rssb.co.uk/rgs/standards/GMRT2473%20Iss%202.pdf) but not automated. Indeed they would be operated by a person, probably the train's guard, pressing a button so they would be manual as well. As opposed to what are usually referred to "in the business" as slam doors

Comment: @Au101 - Nitpick accepted. See edit :-)

Comment: Ta =) Would have +1'ed anyway. For the record, you're not alone, even [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam-door_train) contrasts slam-door trains with trains with 'automatic doors', but following the link to Wikipedia's own article on automatic doors shows why it's an ambiguous choice of terminology, if not wrong